# PriorityQueue poll

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

Looks like PriorityQueue is a LIFO structure (if all the elements in it have same priority), am I right?

```
 public E poll() {
    if (size == 0)
        return null;
    modCount++;

    E result = (E) queue[1];
    queue[1] = queue[size];
    queue[size--] = null;  // Drop extra ref to prevent memory leak
    if (size > 1)
        fixDown(1);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement in the Javadoc that 'ties are broken arbitrarily' means the answer to your question is 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap. The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used. A priority queue does not permit null elements. A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in ClassCastException).
>
> The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering. If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily. The queue retrieval operations poll, remove, peek, and element access the element at the head of the queue.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Basically, there's always a "priority", by default, it's the natural ordering of elements.

Comment: How to explain  queue[1] = queue[size]? that will bring the last element to the head position.

Comment: It's easier if you update your question to ask something specific.